# How to get the underlying type of the pointer using reflect?

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, struct

What I want is to get the fields of `A` through `B`, like

```
type A struct {
  Field_1 string
}
type B struct {
  *A
}

fieldsOfA := someMagicFunc(&B{})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the [`Value`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) reflect object of some variable with  [`reflect.ValueOf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf).

If you also want to modify the variable or its fields, you have to pass the address (pointer) of the variable to `ValueOf()`. In this case the `Value` will belong to the pointer (not the pointed value), but you can use [`Value.Elem()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) to "navigate" to the `Value` of the pointed object.

`*A` is embedded in `B`, so fields of `A` can be referenced from a value of `B`. You can simply use [`Value.FieldByName()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName) to access a field by name in order to get or set its value.

So this does the work, try it on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/TKD9ZvsbKy):

```
b := B{A: &A{"initial"}}
fmt.Println("Initial value:", *b.A)

v := reflect.ValueOf(&b).Elem()
fmt.Println("Field_1 through reflection:", v.FieldByName("Field_1").String())

v.FieldByName("Field_1").SetString("works")
fmt.Println("After modified through reflection:", *b.A)
```

Output:

```
Initial value: {initial}
Field_1 through reflection: initial
After modified through reflection: {works}
```

I recommend to read this blog post to learn the basics of the reflection in Go:

[**The Laws of Reflection**](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)